# Why can't I do a FTP connection via PHP?

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to do a FTP connect with PHP. I read the PHP manual, ftp_connect(), ftp_login(), ftp_get(), ftp_nlist functions.

My code is the following:

```
$host = "ftp://example.com";
$user = "example@example.com";
$password = 'example';

$conn = ftp_connect($host);
$login = ftp_login($conn, $user, $password);

$contents = ftp_nlist($conn, "/example/".$example);

print_r($contents);
```

$contents is empty, ftp_connect too. Why? Where is the error?

Regards

Comment: An error might be in your error log?

Answer (score 0):

May be a problem from the host address using `'ftp://'`, from the [ftp_connect API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php):

> **host:**
>   The FTP server address. This parameter shouldn't have any trailing
>   slashes and shouldn't be prefixed with ftp://.

Comment: I dont know, all the examples have ftp://... is the host

Comment: Have you tried removing it? or tried using ftp.example.com?

Comment: I don't think the user requires the full address either. Try the example from this section [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-login.php#refsect1-function.ftp-login-examples)

Comment: I did it and ftp_connect return empty

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$host = "ftp://example.com";
$user = "example@example.com";
$password = 'example';
```

With:

```
$host = "example.com";  //your domain without ftp://
$user = "example";      //your username without @example.com
$password = 'example';
```

And also:

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn, "/example/".$example);
```

With:

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn, "/example/".$example.""); // added more quotes
```